# save a variable in cookies with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

hi i have a php code and i get id from another page in it i want to save this variable (id) in cookies with javascript. i am new in java but after a lot of search finally i could wrote some codes. this is my current code please take a look at this i think the problem is how i define
 `var favID = $ID;` in my javascript code please help me thanks
ps: please do not suggest saving cookie with pure php  because i did it and it works fine but i want to do some fancier stuff with it for example as u see i want to save id in cookies by click wich is not acceiable with  php

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <a id="addTofav">Add me to fav</a>
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
(is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) ? $ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = $ID");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
$price=$row['price'];
$rent=$row['rent'];
$room=$row['room'];
$date=$row['date']; 
echo"price";
echo"room";
echo"date";
endwhile;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
/*
  * Create cookie with name and value.
  * In your case the value will be a json array.
  */
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = '',
    date = new Date();
    if (days) {
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
  }
  /*
  * Read cookie by name.
  * In your case the return value will be a json array with list of pages saved.
  */
  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=',
    allCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
    i,
    cookie;
    for (i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i += 1) {
      cookie = allCookies[i];
      while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        cookie = cookie.substring(1, cookie.length);
      }
      if (cookie.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
        return cookie.substring(nameEQ.length, cookie.length);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
    var faves = new Array();
$(function(){
    var favID;
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        var favID = (pair[0]=='ID' ? pair[1] :1)
 }
 $(document.body).on('click','#addTofav',function(){
    var fav = {'$ID':favID};
    faves.push(fav);
 var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
    createCookie('favespages', stringified);
    location.reload();
 });
  var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));
    if(myfaves){
    faves = myfaves;
    } else {
    faves = new Array();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why don't you use `localStorage`?

Comment: Is this JS is in the same php page or included?

Comment: @Mohit Bhardwaj hi thank you for your answering cookie is basic it is feasible in every browser  and beside if i solve this problem i think i can get result and i do not want to start from first step with localstorage

Comment: @RIYAJ KHAN hi thank you for your answering it can be in the same page i just want to make it easier for reviewers to check codes

Comment: @Mohit Bhardwaj in one of my codes i used local storage and it worked with google chrome and did not work with firefox. so i decided to use cookies

Comment: That might be the case in earlier times. Current support for `localStorage` is quite good as you can check here http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage . I myself implement it regularly in various projects for various tasks.   And it's quite easy to use even for first timers I think.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your javascript, which I assume is in a different file, is not aware of PHP. You can do the following to define the `$ID` in the javascript variable

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a id="addTofav">Add me to fav</a>
        <?php
            error_reporting(0);
            include("config.php");
            (is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) ? $ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;
            $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = $ID");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
                $price=$row['price'];
                $rent=$row['rent'];
                $room=$row['room'];
                $date=$row['date']; 
                echo"price";
                echo"room";
                echo"date";
            endwhile;
        ?>


        <!-- This part is what you want -->


        <script>
            var favID = <?php $ID ?>; // this gets the variable from PHP and saves it in the javascript variable.
            document.cookie = 'my_id='+favID+'; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/' // save it to a cookie
        </script>


       <!-- till here -->


    </body>
</html>
```

Now on some other page here is how you can get the cookie value:

```
var nameEQ = "my_id=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
var retrieved_id = null
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) retrieved_id = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}

console.log(retrieved_id) // here you will find your ID
```

Now I haven't tested this. Theoretically it should work though.

Comment: hi man thank u for your answering i am gonna test your answer as soon as finish my launch and i am gonna ask your opinion about edited code. :)

Comment: how about this line am i gonna need to change it
`var fav = {'$ID':favID};`

Comment: @user6362236 no you wont need to change it

Comment: as isaid i am new in javascript could u please tell me how can i show results. i mean i save the id with this line `var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);` and then retrieve it with `var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));` and now how can i show it?

Comment: @user6362236 why do you want to save it? once this page loads, your ID will be available to you as `favID` in javascript. Try logging it to your console.

Comment: as a matter of fact i am designing a real estate website and i do all this stuff to let my user to add his or her favorite add to favorite page thus he or she could see his favorite post when ever wants so  i need to save id in cookies and retrieve it in favorite page and fetch the data from data base for this certain id.

Comment: and sorry could u please explain a little more  " Try logging it to your console" i do not know what it is?

Comment: if you write `console.log(favID)` after the PHP code and press F12 to bring up the console window, you will see your ID printed there.

Comment: as i said i need to save id in cookie and retrieve it in some other page thus i think console.log(favID) does not help me. do u have any idea how can i retrieve id ?

Answer (score 1):

After looking your requirement,
You should move this  
    `$ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;`

on Javascript side.As you say,you want better clean code.Don't messup JS and PHP in single file.It's bad one

You should use javascript to access the parameter passed from URL.

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    var ID = (pair[0]=='ID' ? pair[1] :1)
}
```

Then ID is easily available to your JS.

YOUR JS :

```
$(function(){
    var favID;

    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        var favID = (pair[0]=='ID' ? pair[1] :1)
    }

    $(document.body).on('click','#addTofav',function(){
    var fav = {'$ID':favID};
    faves.push(fav);
    var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
    createCookie('favespages', stringified);
    location.reload();
    });
```

EDIT :

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
on current page

```
`localStorage.getItem('ID',10)`
```

On other page where you want to access it.
    `localStorage.getItem('ID');`

Comment: hi thank u for your answering. i did not get your answer. why i have to move this  `$ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;` i mean i have many ads in my website and each of them have a id i send their id to this page and get that id's with this line  `(is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) ? $ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;`

Comment: i think u did not get this line i write it that way to prevent from sql injection. at first it checks that  if id is a number other wise it shows the id=1 results by default

Comment: Sorry for `move`. U dont need to do this thing.Just write the same script in JS way that's it

Comment: no problem man. as i said i am new in jacascript. could u please add your code in my javascript code thanks a lot

Comment: hey man thanks for your updated code. i edited my javascript code in the above could u please check it and also i assume we could save id in cookie but i have a problem i do not know how to show saved id in other page

Comment: could u please take a look at my above question. and help me with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117248/discussion-between-user6362236-and-riyaj-khan).

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all of my friends ( RIYAJ KHAN and Anubhav)finally i got the answer. replace this javascript code instead of question javascript and you will see that it works like a charm.with this u code can save id in cookie and then retrieve it where ever u want

```js
<script>
   /*
  * Create cookie with name and value.
  * In your case the value will be a json array.
  */
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = '',
    date = new Date();
    if (days) {
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
  }
  /*
  * Read cookie by name.
  * In your case the return value will be a json array with list of pages saved.
  */
  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=',
    allCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
    i,
    cookie;
    for (i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i += 1) {
      cookie = allCookies[i];
      while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        cookie = cookie.substring(1, cookie.length);
      }
      if (cookie.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
        return cookie.substring(nameEQ.length, cookie.length);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

    var faves = new Array();
   function isAlready(){
    var is = false;
    $.each(faves,function(index,value){
      if(this.url == window.location.href){
        console.log(index);
          faves.splice(index,1);
          is = true;
      }
    });
    return is;
  }
$(function(){
var url = window.location.href; // current page url
    var favID;
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);

 var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        var favID = (pair[0]=='ID' ? pair[1] :1)
//alert(favID);
 }
 $(document.body).on('click','#addTofav',function(){
       if(isAlready()){
      } else {
          var fav = {'favoriteid':favID,'url':url};
          faves.push(fav);//The push() method adds new items (fav) to the end of an array (faves), and returns the new length.
      }
 var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
    createCookie('favespages', stringified);
    location.reload();
 });
     $(document.body).on('click','.remove',function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      faves.splice(id,1);
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
      createCookie('favespages', stringified);
      location.reload();
    });
  var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));
    if(myfaves){
    faves = myfaves;
    } else {
    faves = new Array();
    }
    $.each(myfaves,function(index,value){
      var element = '<li class="'+index+'"><h4>'+value.favoriteid+'</h4>   '+
      '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove" data-id="'+index+'">Remove me</a>';
      $('#appendfavs').append(element);
    });

});
 </script>
```